# How to integrate Geronimo's transaction manager in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jta, geronimo, transactionmanager

Does Geronimo provides a standalone transaction manager?
And if it does, is it possible to use it in Tomcat?

Answer (score 4):

[Apache OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) is embedded implementation of Geronimo EJB container that includes Transaction Manager. OpenEJB can be embedded into Tomcat which is one of its intended usages.

Comment: Added note that now all this is Java EE 6 certified like JBoss or GlassFish.  New name is Apache TomEE.  Tomcat, with missing parts added.

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want the Geronimo TX manager, then see @topchef's answer.

If you're just looking for a free, open-source TX manager, though, the [JOTM](http://jotm.ow2.org/) is a TX manager that embeds nicely inside Tomcat.

I should ask why you need this, though. If all you need to do is JDBC transactions against a single `DataSource`, then you don't need a TX manager. You only need one if you want to do full JTA transactions.

Comment: Any idea why its been so long since a JOTM release ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Geronimo uses [Jencks](http://jencks.codehaus.org/Transaction+Manager) that can be used standalone. But I can't say it's heavily documented. I'd rather consider using [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/) or [JBossTM](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm/).

#### Related answer

- [Atomikos vs JOTM vs Bitronix vs ????](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978207/atomikos-vs-jotm-vs-bitronix-vs/2978402#2978402)